# appending a template using jquery in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails

in the Jquery code i'm trying to add grails template as follow , but nothing happens:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var div1= $("#div1");
 alert("test");
 div1.append("<g:render template='form'/>")
});
```

i need the final result will be like this:

```
<div id="div1">
<g:render template='form'/>
</div>
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured a way to do this by placing all the needed templates in the page and hide them on page loading and show them later according to some conditions , also don't forget to **disable** the rest of the **divs** for example using Jquery:

```
$('#div2 :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

otherwise you will face problem while submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The `<g:render template='form'/>` tag is processed on the server before it ever goes to the client (browser).  If you use jQuery to change the DOM with the `append` method, you are only altering the generated DOM that the browser is using, whilst the server has no idea.

The server isn't aware of the change, nor can the server change the document once it has been received by the client.

If you want to use the `g:render` tag and change the view after the document is generated, you would need to try an alternate method.  Some possibilities:

- place the template in position but hidden and use jQuery to show the template
- put the template within a `<script>` tag as a string and use jQuery to append the string
- if the template is staic, don't use the `g:render` tag but load the file asynchronously with jQuery and append this

I'm sure there are other ways as well.

Comment: i tried `place the template in position but hidden and use jQuery to show the template` but when i try to submit the form the submit button doesn't work , because i have many templates and will be selected upon some condition , for example `<div id="div1">
<g:render template='form'/>
</div>`  `<div id="div2">
<g:render template='form2'/>
</div>` when i comment **div2** code submit works in **div1** and vise versa although both divs hidden and will be shown with some condition

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this does not work, since `<g:render template='form'/>` is rendered during page `load`. You can make an `AJAX` call to a `controller` and append the result.

Comment: do you got any tutorial for this ?

Comment: There are many tutorials related to AJAX, you just have to know what API, jQuery, Angular,...etc. you want to use and look for the tutorial.